# Imagine Bundle conflict minimum

Tags: symfony, composer-php, liipimaginebundle

I'd like to install **liip/imagine-bundle** in my symfony 2 project. But in order to make barcodes, I installed previously **MopaBarcodeBundle**.

MopaBarcodeBundle requires "avalanche123/imagine-bundle" which requires **imagine/imagine: v0.4.1**

And

LiipImagineBundle requires **imagine/imagine: ~0.5,<0.7**

Obviously composer detects the conflict, as he cannot unistall v0.4.1, and that version is not enough for LiipImagine.

I'd like to know how I could bypass this. Create sorts of aliases in composer and keep the two versions on my project ? I'm not a pro in version management, so I guess this is not possible.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: creating an alias for a different version would not be possible, because you would have conflicting class names.

Comment: You should ask the maintainer of the `MopaBarcodeBundle` to update their package, the `avalanche123/imagine-bundle` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some code inspection i figured out a way around. **MopaBarcodeBundle** doesn't really requires **avalanche123/imagine-bundle**, but it uses it in the service declaration. (To make the link with **Imagine** classes).

So I changed the service.xml file containing the BarcodeService declaration.

```
<parameter key="imagine.gd.class">Imagine\Gd\Imagine</parameter>


<service id="imagine" alias="imagine.gd" /> 
<service id="imagine.gd" class="%imagine.gd.class%" />
```

I guess thoses lines could be factorised, but i chose to keep it as it was done in avalanche123.

Also a constant from avalanche was used in 5th argument, I changed it to :

```
<argument>%kernel.root_dir%../web</argument>
```

Finally I removed avalanche, and then install a newer version of **imagine/imagine**